# Faster way of finding PMI with count vectorizer

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, scikit-learn

First of all I am finding a term document matrix, i.e. a term represented in the dimensions of the number of documents.

For finding PMI, I find the count of bigrams say `this is`, count of individual words in the bigrams `this` and `is` and then calcualte as given in `(4.0 * math.log(1.0*bigramLength,2))/(1.0*math.log(word0Length,2)*math.log(1.0*word1Length,2))`

Is there a faster way to achieve this?  I am not much familiar with `numpy` or `scikit`.

Please note that I need to find the value for every possible bigram in the list `bigramFeatures`

```
f4 = ['this is sentence1','not sentence1 becuase this is not sentence1','why this this is called this is sentence1, its always setence1','fourth time this is not sentene1']


Vcount = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word',ngram_range=(1,2),stop_words='english')
countMatrix = Vcount.fit_transform(f4)

# all unigrams and bigrams
feature_names = Vcount.get_feature_names()

#finding all bigrams
featureBigrams = [item for item in Vcount.get_feature_names() if len(item.split()) == 2 ]

#document term matrix
arrays = countMatrix.toarray()

#term document matrix
arrayTrans = arrays.transpose()

from collections import defaultdict
PMIMatrix = defaultdict(dict)

import math
import numpy
print len(featureBigrams)
i = 0
PMIMatrix = defaultdict(dict)
for item in featureBigrams:
    words = item.split()
    bigramLength = len(numpy.where(arrayTrans[feature_names.index(item)] > 0)[0])
    if bigramLength < 2:
        continue
    word0Length = len(numpy.where(arrayTrans[feature_names.index(words[0])] > 0)[0])
    word1Length = len(numpy.where(arrayTrans[feature_names.index(words[1])] > 0)[0])
    try:
        PMIMatrix[words[0]][words[1]] = (4.0 * math.log(1.0*bigramLength,2))/(1.0*math.log(word0Length,2)*math.log(1.0*word1Length,2))
    except:
        print bigramLength,word0Length,word1Length
```

Comment: You can also refer the [`NLTK collocations`](http://www.nltk.org/howto/collocations.html) package which has pre built ways of finding PMI values of bigram or even trigram elements and it seems to be working quite well.

Comment: @NickilMaveli - I am aware of NLTK collocations. I was just looking for a means of doing the same in my own way :), especially with scikit.

Comment: Why do you multiply by 4?

Comment: Its the number of documents. here there are 4

Comment: If this is too slow for your purposes, then you should really try profiling it to see where the bottlenecks are (see [here](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler)).  But just looking at your code, my first step would be to call CountVectorizer twice, once for unigrams and once for bigrams, rather than calling it once and then having to filter the results.

Also, PMI is usually calculated on the basis of term frequencies rather than document frequencies -- is this even what you want to be doing?